# How to open a .skim file (note file from Skim Note) using java on android

Tags: java, android, pdf, annotations, skim

I’m developing an android application to view the pdf file, take notes... Everything is done and works fine but now, I want to import skim note file (.skim) but I couldn't find anything to do this. Anyone have any sample code or any links which will give me an idea on how can I do that?

Any kind of help in this regard is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @KJ how can i this for android?